# A weird Inequality of the sum of two series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, inequality

I have an inequality which I believe is true but it seems too mysterious to prove it. Suppose $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_{k-1}$ are positive integers such that $$a_0>\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_k $$
I want to prove that $$4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i-\frac{1}{a_0} \left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)a_i\right)^2 \geq k^2a_0$$

The reason why I believe this is true is that $\frac{1}{a_0}$ is a really small number which makes sure the second term on the left is not too big. Induction on $k$, though works on the base case $k=1$, is not very feasible since the square of the sum in the second term would be hard to handle.

Since we are interested in the lower bound, we may substitute $a_0 =\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a_k$ but this may not get any prettier either. Another feasible solution is to use Cauchy-Schwarz on the second term, but it will produce $k^3$ since it would involve the sum of squares.

Here is the approach I'm taking right now, I assume $a_1$ dominates the series of $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_k$, so we have the left term is larger than $$4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i-\frac{1}{a_o}(ka_o+(k-1)a_0)^2= 4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i-(2k-1)^2a_0$$ so we just need to prove $$4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i \geq (5k^2-4k+1)a_0$$
At this stage, I feel this approach may be too aggressive since the left term contains $4k^2a_0$ but $5k^2a_0$ dominates the right term. I always forgot tricks in proving inequalities. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_k$? Or are you summing $a_i$?

Comment: I'm summing $a_i$'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, thanks buddy that was truly an egregious claim, super brainfart so thank you for pointing that out. And now we change our mind on the answer to the Q and try again lol (using $a_0$ to $a_k$ for easier notation):

$$4(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-\frac{1}{a_0}(\sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)a_i)^2\geq k^2a_0$$ becomes
$$4a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-(\sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)a_i)^2\geq k^2a_0^2$$
and we see that
$$4a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-(\sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)a_i)^2=$$
Split the second term into the squares and non-squares:

$$4a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-[(\sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)^2a_i^2)+2(\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq k}(k-i)(k-j)a_ia_j)]\geq$$

In our middle term as $a_0>a_i$,

$$4a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-[(\sum_{i=0}^k(k-i)^2a_0a_i)+2(\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq k}(k-i)(k-j)a_ia_j)]=$$

$$3a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-2(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^k(k-i)(k-j)a_ia_j)\geq$$

Then as for any $0\leq i\leq k-1$, $(k-i)a_0> (k-i)\sum_{j=i+1}^ka_j\geq \sum_{j=i+1}^k (k-j)a_j$, we get $(k-i)a_0 > \sum_{j=i+1}^k(k-j)a_j$ and so the above inequality is greater than the below:

$$3a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-2(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)a_i(k-i)a_0)=$$

$$3a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)-2a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i)=$$

$$a_0(\sum_{i=0}^{k}(k-i)^2a_i)\geq k^2a_0^2$$

as surely

$$\sum_{i=1}^k(k-i)^2a_i\geq 0$$

Hopefully this time I didn't butcher like the last. Sorry again!

Comment: From here $$4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i\geq (5k^2-4k+1)a_0$$ use the same reasoning you did earlier. $$(5k^2-4k+1)a_0\leq 4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(k-i)^2a_i\leq 4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}k^2a_i \leq 4k^2a_0$$ which feels not so good.

Comment: Thanks! I would do more experiments to see if I can actually disprove this

Comment: The last inequality in the Answer does not hold. We can cancel out $a_0^2$ on both sides and we're left with $4 k (1 + 4 + 9 + \dots + k^2) \le (1 + 2 + \dots + k)^2$ which is false.  There are definitely not $2^k$ terms on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks antkam. was seeing the multiplications that looked like $k(k-1)+(k-1)(k-2)$ etc. and thinking a sum of choices gives $2^k$, but wasnt thinking that was coefficients not # terms. I got crazy

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really have the courage to open up the sum of squares. Lesson just learnt and thank you for your effort!